# C# - Firebird obtain more error information

Tags: c#, firebird

```
        string conString = "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=C:\\Users\\dev1\\Desktop\\testdb.fdb;Dialect=3;Charset=UTF8;ServerType=1;";
        FbConnection fcon;

        try
        {
            fcon = new FbConnection(conString);
            string query = "create table test( name varchar(40) );";
            FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(query, fcon);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string errstr = e.Message.ToString();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Error: " + errstr);

        }
```

I only get the error message "Connection must be valid and open"; how do I determine why the connection could not be established exacty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `fcon.Open()` to open the connection.

Comment: also don't forget to close it

Comment: Don't forget to close it afterwards... or wrap it in a using statement if it implement IDisposable (which it should do)

Comment: Thanks, did not know you have to open the connection explicitly!